# Referencing object's property name with hyphen

Tags: javascript

I have defined an object with properties that have hyphen in their names.

```
var data = {
  "foo-bar": "value",
  "this-that": "another value"
}
```

Now I need to reference this property in JS, but both these ways result in syntax error.

```
console.log( data.foo-bar )
```

and

```
console.log( data."foo-bar" )
```

So my question is. How can I access a property that contains hyphen in the name in JS?

---

*Disclaimer: The server-side functionality require hyphen-naming of the properties and I don't really feel like rewriting somebody else's whole script that takes the input params like this. And yes, I know this current way is not the most clean approach possible.*

Comment: [MDN Presents: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and its spin-off [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Could use `data["foo-bar"]` Instead.